# How can I see the entire SCM history in my Xcode project?

Tags: xcode, history, version-control

If I look at the SCM tab in Get Info for my project I only see the commits that affected the project file. Where can I get a list of all the commits for the entire project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode 4: go to Organizer (top right), Repositories, choose repository, there it is.

Comment: I originally asked about Xcode 3, but I don't even use it anymore. I'll probably never use Xcode 3's SCM functionality again, so I guess an Xcode 4 answer is more relevant.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 5 you can choose View > Navigators > Log.  From here you can see each of your Updates and Commits in the left pane for actions that have happened since opening the project.

For a general history choose Source Control > History…  This will bring up something similar that what Xcode 4 had in the organizer.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem viewing the entire SCM history (Subversion in this case) when viewing the Repositories tab in the Organizer from XCode 4.02 where I could only see revisions for the selected folder in the History pane, and revisions from sub directories would not be shown.

In order to see the full history (i.e. the visual equivalent of 'svn log' on the project) you need to select either the Repository Root (purple icon) or a Branch (yellow icons) for your project.

After selecting either of these icons the history pane should now show all revisions, including revisions to sub directories, which would not otherwise be shown if a Working Copy (blue icon) is selected in the left hand pane.