# Where does Xcode 4 store its subversion log?

Tags: xcode, svn, logging

I have a problem communicating with our SVN server and would like to see what the conversation between Xcode 4 and SVN looks like. We're using https, so I can't wire shark it, and would prefer to look at logs anyway.

There is nothing in the normal Log Navigator and nothing in the console log.

The error I get from Xcode 4 is a sheet that says: "The working copy "Working" failed to commit files." "The request could not be performed because it was returned by Subversion as invalid.". The changed file is not committed.

I am able to do a checkout and can browse, diff, etc., but ran into the same problem with update. Command line and svnx work perfectly. We used to run ssh+svn and that worked fine with Xcode 4, so it is probably this change that has broken things. Certificates have been accepted on the clients and passwords entered into Xcode, as expected.

Comment: The solution to the Xcode problem was to delete the old repository in Xcode. However, I still want to know how to view the logs.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045937/how-can-i-see-the-entire-scm-history-in-my-xcode-project

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 4: Go to `Organizer` - `Repositories` - choose repository.

To see the full history (i.e. the visual equivalent of 'svn log' on the project) you need to select either the Repository Root (purple icon) or a Branch (yellow icons) for your project.